# Need a tab arranging functionality in html/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As just like firefox re-arranging tabs functionality... is there any online javascript open-source code to reuse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#sortable

Comment: No problems, if you could mark the question as answered that'd be great :)